# Qt. Как обратится к форме из другого файла

Tags: qt, классы, form, ui

Есть файлы mainwindow.h, hash.h, mainwindow.cpp, hash.cpp.

Файл hash.cpp:

```
    #include "hash.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include "mainwindow.h"


     void HashMap::put(int key, QString value) {

               int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
               int m = TABLE_SIZE;

               while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)

                // hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;

               hash = (( hash + 1 ) % m-2 ) + 1;

               if (table[hash] != NULL){

                     delete table[hash];}

               table[hash] = new HashEntry(hash, value);

               //ui->lineEdit->SetText("")  -  как сделать так?
         }
```

В общем, мне нужно, чтобы я как то достучался из этой функции до своей формы и вставил значение в `LineEdit`. Она находится в `mainwindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни в коем случае в форму так "стучаться" не следует. Ваш класс `HashMap` должен быть свободен от какого бы то ни было знания о пользовательском интерфейсе. Уберите сразу

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
```

из файла `hash.cpp`. Код, который вызывает `put`, должен знать о форме и обращаться к ней.

Если это по какой-то причине невыполнимо, организуйте уведомление подписчиков о действиях/событиях в `HashMap`.